# Regex to match keywords inside specific context

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am new to regular expressions. Basically, I would like to match all instances of "private", but only when they appear within the argument list of a constructor.

Here is my example text:

```
constructor(
  private optionsService: OptionsService,
  private modalService: BsModalService,
  private renderer: Renderer2,
  private messageService: MessageService,
  private queryBuilderService: QueryBuilderService,
  private ltPlacementService: LtPlacementService,
  private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
) { } // All of the above should match

private someOtherVariable; // Should not match
```

Is there a way to match everything within the constructor(...) { } and then match instances of "private" only in this result? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match from `constructor(` to `) {` you could use [`constructor\(([\s\S]+(?=\)\s*{))`](https://regex101.com/r/7hJqw8/1) and then capture the text in between in a capturing group (group 1).

That will match

- `constructor` Match literally
- `\(` Match (
- `(` Capturing group (group 1)

  - `[\s\S]+` Match any whitespace or non whitespace character
  - `(?=` Positive lookahead that asserts what follows

    - `\)\s*{` Match ), zero or more whitespaces and {
  - `)` Close positive lookahead
- `)` Close capturing group

Then match `private` in from the text in group 1:

[`\bprivate\b`](https://regex101.com/r/98tFj8/1)

For example:

```js
let string = `constructor(
  private optionsService: OptionsService,
  private modalService: BsModalService,
  private renderer: Renderer2,
  private messageService: MessageService,
  private queryBuilderService: QueryBuilderService,
  private ltPlacementService: LtPlacementService,
  private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
) { } // All of the above should match

private someOtherVariable; // Should not match`;

const pattern = /constructor\(([\s\S]+(?=\)\s*{))/g;
pattern.exec(string)[1].match(/\bprivate\b/g).forEach((p) => {
  console.log(p);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I eventually accomplished my goal using AWK, but I'm sure this would be very helpful to another distraught programmer. Marking as accepted. Cheers :)